# Why does a getView call on a support fragment return null during a unit test but doesn't with a standard fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-testing

I'm trying to learn about unit testing in Android and have been writing a test for a fragment.  I've found that when using the platform fragments getView returns the fragment's view fine.  However, when I use a support fragment getView returns null during the test.

I've created a sample project to demonstrate this at https://github.com/appassembla/fragmenttestingsample.  Running HelloWorldExampleActivityTest passes fine but HelloWorldExampleActivityTest2 fails because getView is null in the support fragment.  I'm using Android Studio to run the tests.

Not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong or whether there is a problem with support fragments.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

My test class is as follows:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase;

public class HelloWorldExampleActivity2Test extends ActivityUnitTestCase<HelloWorldExampleActivity2> {

    public HelloWorldExampleActivity2Test() {
        super(HelloWorldExampleActivity2.class);
    }

    private HelloWorldExampleActivity2 activity;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        startActivity(new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
            HelloWorldExampleActivity2.class), null, null);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the fragment to a the activity, thereby fully initializing its view.
     */
    private void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(fragment, null).commit();
        manager.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    public void testSimpleFragment() {
        SimpleFragment2 fragment = new SimpleFragment2();
        startFragment(fragment);

        assertNotNull(fragment.getView());
    }
}
```

My activity is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HelloWorldExampleActivity2 extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_world_example);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hello_world_example, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My fragment is:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link android.app.Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SimpleFragment2 extends Fragment {


    public SimpleFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple, container, false);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should take a look at creating an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as they it's rare for those looking through questions to get/build your whole project or example. In this case just display the relevant activity and test code in your question using the code markdown http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: When debugging the fragment extending the support library fragment onCreateView isn't called but it is when debugging a fragment that extends the platform fragment.  This is why getView is null but why does the support fragment's onCreateView not get called?

Comment: Hi richarth, Yes you are right actually. I have being trying to do this whole day(by different hooks) but getview was always null for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but after reading your post i tried it with `android.app.Fragment` and it worked. This must be a bug in support that it doesn't support junit. Thanks a lot. Did you find any solution to get it work with Support fragments?

Comment: BTW i just reported bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176191&thanks=176191&ts=1433761754

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a solution.  Fortunately older versions are dying off so we should be able to use native fragments moving forward.